# How to check if a checkbox is checked

Tags: servlets, checkbox

i have checkbox on the form

```
<input class="addToFavorite" type="checkbox" name="addToFavorite"> Add to favorite
```

now when form posting i check if this checkbox checked with this code. But it return true every time. how i can check if checkbox has been really checked?

```
boolean wantAddToFavorites = false;
            if (isPayAction) {
                wantAddToFavorites = request.getParameter("addToFavorite").equals("on");
            }
```

FireBug result

[image]

as you see It always send its value

Comment: Can u describe more for this question. I saw few thing missing here like value from check box.

Comment: @Smutje- java tag is attached with questions.

Comment: please add more tags

Comment: it was just my problem. So i forgot that i post form via ajax. where i post form which i create dynamically and forget to put this checkbox value to this form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to check on server-side if a checkbox has been checked or not, you should do the following:

**1.** Add a value to your checkbox

```
<input class="addToFavorite" type="checkbox" name="addToFavorite" value="addToFavourite"> Add to favorite</input>
```

**2.** Check this checkbox value on server-side

```
if(request.getParameter("addToFavorite") == null){
    //checkbox not checked
}else{
    //checkbox checked
}
```

Comment: no it does not work. i have added value attribute to the checkbox. but  condition request.getParameter("addToFavorite") == null everytime returns true

Comment: Check again your checkbox name and the value from `getParameter(..)` call. They must match, else it'll not work. Also make sure that the name you've used for your checkbox is unique. If you've grouped multiple checkboxes under the same name , then you must use `request.getParameterValues("addToFavorite")`

Comment: please see my post. i have added FireBug screenshot

Comment: Please update your post with more from your server-side code. Maybe that's where the problem is. I'm quite sure that this must work.

Comment: yes you are right. it must work. But does not work now on me. I have added server side code before

Comment: I see your server-side code as being : `wantAddToFavorites = request.getParameter("addToFavorite").equals("on");` . Did you try the following : `wantAddToFavorites = request.getParameter("addToFavorite") != null;` ?

Comment: yeees of course. as you see on FireBug it posts it's value. And your condition to check is not null will be false

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59652/discussion-between-daniel-and-aemloviji).

Answer (score 3):

In a checkbox, the value attribute holds the string that will be sent if the box is checked. By default it sends the string "on".

What determines whether it is checked or not is the checked attribute.

Example:

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="check1" checked />               Sends "on"  
    <input type="checkbox" name="check2" />                       Sends null
    <input type="checkbox" name="check3" value="hello" checked /> Sends "hello"  
    <input type="checkbox" name="check3" value="hello" />         Sends null.
```

Comment: Very well explained